# How to make /index/ not required in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an index page on which I need an optional parameter, so I'm doing this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("EventRegistration/Index/{status?}")]
public ActionResult Index(string status)
{
    ....
}
```

This works great so long as the URL is:

```
http://localhost:49698/EventRegistration/Index
```

Or

```
http://localhost:49698/EventRegistration/Index/something
```

But with this:

```
http://localhost:49698/EventRegistration
```

It throws a 404.  Before adding the optional parameter, it worked fine without the `/Index'.  I'd like it to keep doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: Apply two route attributes?

Comment: Didn't know you could do that.  What would the second one look like?

Comment: `[Route("EventRegistration")]` I guess.

Comment: yeah that worked.  Make it an answer?  I'll mark it as such

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find a duplicate. I'm fairly sure this has been answered before, but if I, knowing what to search for, can't even find it, I can't imagine you finding it. Feel free to self-answer. I'm also not quite certain if using two attributes is the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I've seen the syntax `[Route("[action=index]")]` but it may apply to .net core only - so a default for a route segment. I think it would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("EventRegistration/Index/{status?}")]
[Route("EventRegistration")]
public ActionResult Index(string status)
{
    ....
}
```